# How do I delete spaces from a string?

Tags: string, delphi

I want to delete spaces from a string value. For example, `sString := 'Hello my name is Bob` should become `sString := 'HellomynameisBob`.

I tried using the while loop:

```
iPos := pos(' ', sString);
while iPos > 0 do
Delete(sString,iPos,1);
```

but the program just freezes.

Answer (score 20):

The program freezes because you never increment the `iPos` in your loop.

Simplest solution is to use Delphi function declared in `SysUtils` - `StringReplace` ([reference](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StringReplace)) like so:

```
newStr := StringReplace(srcString, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]); //Remove spaces
```

Answer (score 4):

```
iPos := pos(' ', sString);
while iPos > 0 do begin
  Delete(sString,iPos,1);
  iPos := pos(' ', sString);
end;
```

Comment: This will be very slow for very long strings, as it continually searches from the beginning of the string. StringReplace will be much faster than this.

Answer (score 1):

While @Kromster is right, this far not the right approach to deal with this.
You should use the StringReplace Function where you pass `sString` , the character to replace, the character to replace with, and some built-in flags. so your code should look like this:

```
sString := 'Hello my name is Bob;
newString := stringReplace(sString, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

`newString` should now return `'HellomynameisBob'`.

Comment: What do you mean with *...this far not the right approach...*, when you refer to @Kromster's answer? How is your answer any better?